# Не работает запрос vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, requests

помогите пожалуйста поправить запрос. Я хочу собрать записи в группе. Вроде бы согластно документации это правильный запрос, но он постоянно возвращает  'error_code': 3, 'error_msg': 'Unknown method passed'

```
import requests
id_group = 'id'
token = 'token'
version = '5.131'

response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id={}&access_token={}&v={}'.format(id_group, token, version))
response = response.json()
print(response)
```

В документации эта ошибка "неизвестный метод", но этот метод есть https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызвать функцию:

```
import requests


def get_wall_posts(VK_TOKEN: str) -> dict:
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get'
    params = {
        'access_token': VK_TOKEN, # ваш токен
        'owner_id': -1, # id сообщества указывается со знаком - перед цифрами
        'v': '5.131', # версия API
        'count': 1 # сколько постов получить
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return response.json()


wall_posts = get_wall_posts(VK_TOKEN)
print(wall_posts)
```

Например, тут мы возьмем последний пост из группы [ВКонтакте API](https://vk.com/club1).
При работе с VK API идентичная ошибка редко, но возникала и решилось все просто отключением IPv6.